# How to replace all existence value with something else

Tags: python, json, replace

I would like to find a simple way to replace values in a JSON file.

I am looking for something similar to:

```
json_file.replace("-", "")
```

SAMPLE:

```
"scores": {
                "count": 1,
                "my-followings": 420,
                "my-plain-tweets": 0,
                "my-tweets-with-links": 1,
                "my-tweets-with-image": 0,
                "my-replies": 0,
                "my-listed": 113,
                "my-retweets": 0,
                "my-statuses": 3653,
                "my-followers": 8536,
                "favourites": 0,
                "my-tweets-with-video": 0,
                "my-favourites": 7929,
                "retweets": 0
            }
```

EXPECTED:

```
"scores": {
                "count": 1,
                "myfollowings": 420,
                "myplaintweets": 0,
                "mytweetswithlinks": 1,
                "mytweetswithimage": 0,
                "myreplies": 0,
                "mylisted": 113,
                "myretweets": 0,
                "mystatuses": 3653,
                "myfollowers": 8536,
                "favourites": 0,
                "mytweetswithvideo": 0,
                "myfavourites": 7929,
                "retweets": 0
            }
```

Added sample and what I expected.

Comment: why is the code you posted not good for you? looks like a fine way to remove all dashes

Comment: Can you post a sample of your JSON and expected output?

Comment: @Rakesh Updated, have a look....

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I know it should, I'm sure it some silly mistake, just can't figure out, what.

Comment: @DenisSineiko But what does it do instead? What's the output or error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.replace`

**Demo:**

```
import json
with open(filename, "r") as infile:                    #Read json
    data = json.load(infile)

data = dict((k.replace("-", ""), v) for k, v in data["scores"].items())  #Remove "-"
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:                    #Write back to file
    data = json.dump({"scores": data}, outfile)
```

*Edit as per comment*

```
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read().replace("-", "")

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: This is a good example, thank you... but is it any possibility to replace in WHOLE JSON file ... ( Like you one Note++ click CTRH+H and replace all existant symbol with something else)

Comment: Updated snippet. You can chain the replace function with the symbols you need replaced. Ex: `.replace("-", "").replace("*", "").replace("?", "")`

Comment: When I read and replace, all good ( it does work, I can read the file and it does replace), but when I write it back to file (file is empty) with no error. The issue with writing the data to the same file ( as if I write to different one, it does work.

Comment: Are you using the code exactly as posted in the above example?

Comment: Thank you, I  have changed it to w+ and it start working good)

Comment: Could you please forward me with - how I can improve this question? as I believe, have asked the good question, and received the great answer,  but have (negatives votes.......

Answer (score 1):

The command-line tool [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is designed for this type of problem.

For example, suppose you want to change ALL the hyphens in ALL the key names (but only key names) in ALL objects,
no matter how deeply nested:

```
walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(.key |= gsub("-";"")) else . end)
```

If you only wanted to change the FIRST hypen, you'd change the `gsub` to `sub`.

In case your jq does not have `walk/1`, you can include its definition, e.g.

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(.key |= gsub("-";"")) else . end)
```

### Invocation with `sponge`

If you want to overwrite the input file, then a utility such as `sponge` would come in handy. For example, if the JSON is in a file, say input.json, and if the jq program as above is in program.jq, then you could proceed as
follows:

```
jq -f program.jq input.json | sponge input.json
```